# How to add parameters to WebMatrix Database.Query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webmatrix

Using Database.Query has has made [a huge improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905249/1152809) on readability in my code:

```
String Select = 'sp_getAllUsers';
WebMatrix.Data.Database DB = WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open(MyConString);
var data = DB.Query(Select);
```

I'd like to switch to a non-stored procedure query. The [MSDN says there's an optional parameter to the Query Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.query%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), `Object[]`, that can be passed as SQL parameters, however they don't have any further information about it.

So I have two questions:

- How can I create a `Object[]`?
- Will adding parameters in this way prevent hacking threats, such as SQL Injection?

Here's an abridged version of what I have tried:

```
Select = "Select * From Users Where first_name = "Foo" AND last_name = "Bar"

// Like Javascript
Object[] params = {"first_name" : "Foo"}, {"last_name" : "Bar"};

// More Like What I think it will be
Object[] Params = (String Name = "first_name", String First_Name = "Foo");

var data = DB.Query(Select, params);
```

All the sources I've looked at only seem to reference [the old way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905249/1152809). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471744/webmatrix-database-query-with-custom-commandtimeout) is close, but he doesn't use the parameter parameter of the Query method.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this syntax:

```
string selectCommand = "sp_getAllUsers(@0, @1)";
// selectCommand = "Select * From Users Where first_name = @0 AND last_name = @1";
...
var data = DB.Query(selectCommand, "Foo", "Bar");
```

More info, see:
http://www.aspnet101.com/2010/07/webmatrix-tutorial-working-with-data/

Also, using a Parameter will always prevent SQL Injection as it always double quote a single quote.

Comment: This worked, however, my other question wasn't answered, Will this method of adding parameters prevent SQL injection? Or should I do this: `Select * From Users Where first_name = N'@0' AND last_name = N'@1'`?

Comment: Using Parameters will always prevent SQL Injection as they always double quote a single quote.

Comment: if this solved your issue, please make it as the solution. Thanks!  :)